# Images not showing in single product page woocommerce / elementor

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, elementor

Everything seem to be working fine and all of the sudden my product images in the single product page disappeared. https://viabl.space/shop/art/ananda/

I have tried to unactivate all plugins which didn't work.
I have also tried to check for the opacity which seems to be a problem for others but couldn't find any opacity Style.

I'm using WordPress Elementor and the Astra theme.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Themes » Customize. You will see your site’s live preview with a bunch of options on the left pane. Click on the Additional CSS tab from the left pane. Paste the following CSS into Additional CSS editor:

```
.woocommerce-product-gallery {
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

Don’t forget to click on the ‘Save & Publish’ button on the top when you are finished.

Comment: Thanks ! That worked like a charm for my main product image. 

Yet the other images for the same product don't appear as they should in a thumbnail version bellow the main image.  

Do you have an idea of what could be done for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Due to console error, flex slider JavaScript is not working. You used indexof function in your code but it created the error.